# How to call helper method through select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, onchange, helper, html-select

I am trying to call helper method from select_tag. I tried this:

```
<%= select_tag(:themes, options_for_select({"Black" => "compiled/styles", "Green" => "compiled/styles2"})) %>
```

When I put `alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)` instead of calling method, it works. How can I change my code to call the method as desired?

*EDIT*

I have this on my `application.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#display_themes').change(function(){
       $.ajax({url: '<%= url_for :controller => 'application', :action => 'set_themes()', :id => 'this.value' %>',
               data: 'selected=' + this.value,
               dataType: 'script'
       }) 
   })
});
```

And in controller I have set_themes methode

```
def set_themes()
      @themes = params[:id]
      respond_to do |format|
        redirect_to '/galleries'
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @themes }
    end
end
```

The problem now is @themes still empty even I change the dropdown

Routes.rb

```
match '', :controller => 'application', :action => 'set_themes()'
```

Comment: apperently remote_function doesn't work in rails 3

Comment: Can you show how `set_themes` is initialised, and what it does?

Answer (score 1):

To route to `application#set_themes`:

```
match '/set_themes', to: 'application#set_themes', as: :set_themes
```

With that done, just direct the url in ajax as follows:

```
$.ajax({url: "<%= set_themes_path %>",
```

It should be **`@themes = params[:selected]`** in your controller based on what you are trying to do in *application.js*.

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that I already deleted the :onchange => set_themes.
I think the problem is on the routes, because I routed like this :
match '', :controller => 'application', :action => 'set_themes()'
without params. how to route it with params?
See the edited version 3 to see the set_themes function, please. and thank you for answering :-) really appreciate it

Comment: Please edit your question to show your relevant routes in _routes.rb_, as well as edit to set `@themes` to `params[:id]`, and change the quotes appropriately in `$.ajax({url: ...`.

Comment: I have edited my question, changed the quotation. Should I change the function set_themes to params[:id] ? Because I only want to make the @themes to my value from dropdown which is the parameter.

Comment: `@themes = params[:id]`. Your code is a little messy right now, so I am just pointing out errors which may not necessarily resolve your problem. I've edited my answer to suit your current questions. It will also help if you would edit your entire question to show only the current code, and describe exactly what you wish to do.

Comment: @takodil, I've edited my answer again. Hopefully this time `@themes` will have a value. If it doesn't, check your browser's developer tools to see if there are any javascript errors with the ajax call.